# Getting TypeError: path.split is not a function in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Error:

node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1160
const subpaths = path.split(/./g);
^

TypeError: path.split is not a function
at Schema.hasMixedParent (C:\Users\Travis\Desktop\Cop_Botv1\Cop_Site_Discord\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1160:25)
at Schema.path (C:\Users\Travis\Desktop\Cop_Botv1\Cop_Site_Discord\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:636:23)
at C:\Users\Travis\Desktop\Cop_Botv1\Cop_Site_Discord\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2410:39

The error happens with this post.

```
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    let id = 'sdflksjdflksd'; 
    let activated = false;
    let end_date = '10/2'; 
    let email = 'random@gmail.com'
    let key = {key_id: id, end_date: end_date, activated: false, email: email }
    Keys.create(key, (err, result) => {
        if(err) console.log(err); 
        else {
            console.log(result); 
        }
    })
})
```

Schema File

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

let keySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    key_id: String, 
    end_date: String, 
    activated: Boolean,
    email: String 
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model("Keys", keySchema);
```

The error is in the lib, not really sure what path is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check model hooks e.g 'pre', 'save' etc., I had the same issue,

I was using `this` keyword in the wrong place as shortcut [lazyness] for all properties

Mistake

```
objectSchema.pre('save', async function(){

     if(this.isModified(this)) do something() 

});
```

Solution

```
objectSchema.pre('save', async function(){

    if(this.isModified('property')) do something()

});
```

I hope this example may help you find your own solution to your issue.